# What is the correct way for nomenclature of millions of images?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a image upload form which would upload large (may be millions) of records. Something like profile images of users, Currently we are giving the nomenclature as

```
'some_constant_string'.time().[image_file_extension];
```

**for eg.** `'tcs'.time().'jpg';`
Does it a right approach or it will produce some duplicacy by the time. Please help on the correct way to do it!

Currently Using PHP 5.6 with Codeigniter Framework 3.0

Comment: try `uniqid(time())`

Comment: You can use date time combination date(d-m-y H:i:s). It will be unique always. Also you can get date and time of image upload from its name

Comment: It will not be unique, and litterly is just as efficient as time(), as both differ *per second*.

Comment: It will also include seconds in name then why it will be not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect a lot of files to be uploades I would change the approach a little.

I will change the naming to something like this:

```
<user_id> . '_' .microtime(true) . <img_extension>
```

Then you will have less problems with duplicate images because two images for the same user should be processed in the same microsecond. If you think you could still having problems you could try with this:

```
<user_id> . '_' . microtime(true) . '_' . <inc> . <img_extension>
```

Here the value of  could be a counter in soee a loop to rename images or an auto increment field in a db id you need a centralized approach.

Another think you should take care is how to store all the images. Putting all of then in the same folder is a bad idea so in adittion to the name I will recommen to create a forder structure, for example:

You have this file:

```
123_1498116500_1.jpg
```

You can split to a folder structure like this:

```
/123/149/811/650/123_1498116500_1.jpg
```

With this structure you will avoid some overhead when the operation system should manages folders with thousand of files.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: You can split to a folder structure like this:

`/123/149/811/650/123_1498116500_1.jpg`

Please help how to make split algorithm for this approach. Your idea is perfect.

Comment: An esay way is to use str_split function this will return an array of chunks of your string, then join it with '/'. Something like this $folder = '/' . implode('/', str_split($img_name, 3));  Not tested ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is not the right approach. If two users fire the upload event at the same moment, they both'll have 1234.jpg, resulting in at least one confused user.

For unique names, there is [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid). That'll fix your current problem.

But, ***there is another (IMO better) solution***: **Use proper dirnames**, e.g. `/uploads/user_id/some-image.jpg`. This'll give you a lot more advantages.
At the very least, duplicate filenames is (nearly) impossible. You can now also use functions like `scandir()` a lot more efficient, as you dont have to check huge amounts of images. And if you delete a user, you simply delete `/uploads/user_id/` and you've easily removed all their images.

Answer (score 0):

Since `time()` has (obviously) a one-second resolution, you'd need to throttle your image processing to one per second. But a day has only 86,400 seconds on average—just do the maths.

[uniqid()](http://php.net/uniqid) should be a better alternative—don't forget to enable the `$more_entropy` parameter.

Comment: As per the guidelines of PHP they are giving me a warning

Warning
This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value. Since most systems adjust system clock by NTP or like, system time is changed constantly. Therefore, it is possible that this function does not return unique ID for the process/thread. Use more_entropy to increase likelihood of uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

the duplicacy of an image is possible, but it can happens only if 2 or more users upload an image at the same time.
You can use an MD5 (or something else) to identify uniquely your image, or use something like `uniqid()`